# What are the technical benefits of creating a BO, DO, DTO, DAO only to perform a SELECT on primary ID?

Tags: java, architecture, callstack

I'm working on a Java codebase and being new to the Java community. I've used Java independently but never with a team that is possibly doing *idiomatic* Java.

The objective is to perform a `SELECT` on a primary key. To do this there is the codebase creates a [business object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Objects), a [data object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Data_Objects), a [data transfer object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and a [data access object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object). They are not all create in the same method. There is a deep call stack who's only objective is to create one of these from the other. Finally the DAO uses a `QueryEngine` object to talk to the persistent store. The `QueryEngine` does the job of abstracting the persistent store.

I see the value in abstracting the persistent store because you keep the flexibility to change it what's underneath without breaking your clients. I love objects as much as the next guy but I don't see why you'd write code this way? Is this idiomatic Java because the whole codebase is filled with these?

**PS:** I'm ignoring the discussion about the performance hit due to memory allocation caused by seemingly unnecessary object creation and method calls.

**PPS:** The language used is Java and also all Wikipedia pages linked here seem low quality and Java specific although they try to sound general to computer science.

Answer (score 1):

There is always an inverse relationship between loose coupling and performance.

With each new version of frameworks , loose coupling increases and performance decreases. But there is a catch here, the hardware configurations is improving at a much faster pace and hence compensating well for the performance degradation.

Performance degradation because of Extra objects, function calls is the discussion of past , Today the priority is to make the application loosely coupled and scalable.

In your case though your flow might not require so many objects but its good to have consistent flow so as to help new programmer to understand it well.  There might be other requests which needs such level of loose coupling.

Comment: I'm not sure what the value of this lose coupling is here though? The purpose of all of these layers is just one — to abstract the persistent store. No?

Answer (score 0):

There are many advantages:
1. Re-usability-others can use your part of code if exposed which makes it more generic.
2. Maintenance
3. Testing
4. Security- Expose only what is required.
5. Adding additional requirements will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is best practice to divide whole system into multiple layers. I can see from your description that you application has a data layer which is quite generic. 
As mentioned by Vivek, adding these layers may provide you loose coupling but would reduce performance. Similarly there is an inverse relationship between maintainability & ease of writing code. In your case, designer has taken care of maintainability. In normal circumstances, with such complex structure, companies have code generation tools. These tools generate code for all tables & views and provide high level objects to developer. Developer simply use these objects to access & modify data. This is encapsulation provided by most of Object Oriented Programming languages like Java.